# Android Emulator Pixel Not Clear when run on mac pro retina 13"

Tags: android, macos

I have just start using mac book for android and iOS development.

The problem is when I run android emulator its resolution or pixel not in a good shape and unclear. Is this a normal behaviour on mac?? or do I miss somethings??

> MacBook Pro Retina 13"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its the high resolution of your Retina screen. Here is an article that describes the effect.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/why-do-some-apps-look-bad-on-my-retina-display-and-how-to-fix-it/